# Get a full string from a byte* using python ctypes with a C dll

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I have to call from python3.3 the following C dll function , knowing that I have to allocate memory space for the answer which will be a in byte table starting from the adress of the ***response*** pointer :

`LONG Read_Parameters(BYTE dst, BYTE src, SHORT* param_list, BYTE param_number, BYTE* response);`

I use ctypes like this

> ```
>     Read_Parameters = getattr(lib2, "Read_Parameters")
>     Read_Parameters.argtypes = [c_byte,c_byte, POINTER(c_short),c_byte,POINTER(c_byte)]
>     Read_Parameters.restype = c_long
>     param_list = (c_short) (0)
>     answer=(c_byte)()
>     l = Read_Parameters(32,0,param_list,1,(answer))
>     print(str(chr((answer.value))))
> ```

With this code I only print the first character of the string I want to read through this dll's call.
How can I allocate correctly the memory from python and read the correct whole output string value ??
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: No src & dst are numbers for specific devices and are not linked to my problem. param_number is the number of parameter ID read in this call and param_list is the list of parameter ID read. So here in my call only 1 parameter is read and its ID is 0. I suppose that's the answer is less than 255 character. Sorry I hope now it is clearer! thanks for your help

Comment: I think it will be clearer to use `param_list = (c_short * 1)()`, though it isn't strictly necessary for a length 1 array. An array is initialized to 0s. Is `response` a known fixed size? Say that size is `N`, then use `answer = (c_byte * N)()`. The array doesn't have a `value` attribute, but it can be indexed, e.g. `answer[0]`, or sliced, e.g. `answer[:]`. A `c_byte` is numeric, so the results of the latter are numbers. Do you want a string instead?

Comment: Yes absolutetly but I didn't know this syntax... so now I can get the whole string with the following code:        l = Read_Parameters(32,0,param_list,1,(answer))
        string=""
        for i in range(0,255):
            string+=(chr(answer[i]))
            if (answer[i]) == 0:
                break
        print(string)                         Thanks a lot my problem is solved!!!

Comment: If you want a string, use `POINTER(c_char)` for the `response` parameter in `argtypes`, and `answer = (c_char * 255)()`. Then call `Read_Parameters(32, 0, param_list, 1, answer)`, and the null-terminated string is `answer.value` or use `answer.raw` to include trailing nulls.

Comment: If the response size is not in fact fixed, then maybe (and this is speculation) it's the return value when you call `Read_Parameters` with a `NULL` pointer for `response`, e.g. `size = Read_Parameters(32, 0, param_list, 1, None)`. Then set `answer = (c_char * size)()` and call the function again, passing the `answer` buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these details eryksun! You have been very helpful!!!